# Firebase custom objects with @Exclude annotation vs obfuscation

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, obfuscation

I'm working on an Android-app (written in Java) that stores custom objects in Cloud Firestore. As described in the documentation, I've used `@Exclude`-annotation on getter-methods for instance variables I don't want to store in the database. For example, the object A has a variable called `documentId`, which refers to the Firestore `docId` in itself and doesn't need to be stored as a key-value pair in the document. The object also has some more variables with special properties that are treated separately from the main process of writing the document to database. For instance a `GeoPoint` object, which is stored in the document using the **GeoFirestore** library, and should be excluded from the main process of writing the object to the database. A simplified model class is shown below.

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude;

//@Keep annotation added after obfuscation was implemented
@Keep
public class myClass {
    private String a;
    private int b;
    private String docId;

    public myClass(){
        //empty constructor required for Cloud Firestore
    }

    public myClass(String a, int b, String docId) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.docId = docId;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getB() { 
        return b; 
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getDocId() {
        return docId;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setDocId(String docId) {
        this.docId = docId;
    }
```

Database output if `a="a"` and `b=3`:

```
someDocumentId = {a: "a", b: 3}
```

This has been working as expected up until now, some variables are stored to database, others are treated separate. But now I've started using obfuscation and minifying code, initially without anything added to the proguard file. This gave a lot of problems due to some necessary empty constructors. After adding `@Keep` annotation on those constructors I was still getting errors related to serialization of objects etc. To avoid having to micromanage all this, and since I'm new to obfuscation, I just added @Keep annotation for all the model classes, as there is no redundant code there anyway. That got rid of all the errors. However, now the Firestore `@Exclude` annotation doesn't work anymore, the excluded variables are now written to the documents along with everything else, but since they don't have values at the time of storing to database, their values are null. So far, this doesn't seem to be a problem, but it does give a lot of cluttering of the documents, and I'm not convinced it cant give unforeseen issues in the future.

Current database output:

```
someDocumentId = {a: "a", b: 3, docId: null}
```

So to summarize:
Does the annotation `androidx.annotation.Keep` override `com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude`?
How can I get rid of the unwanted variables in the database when `@Exclude` doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you'll want to add an `@Exclude` annotation to the setter as well.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I'll try that. I'm not really sure where I picked up that it was only needed for the getter, this is my first large app so I'm still learning. It has been running without `@Exclude` on the setter all along. Before the obfuscation it was working as I intended with the docId (and others) being skipped when the object is stored, that's why I haven't looked into the setters.

Comment: Yeah, not having `Exclude` on the setter might work as there's nothing to set if the ID isn't in the database to begin with. But it's worth a shot.

Comment: Hey @Leknesh! Have you tried Frank's solution?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've tried adding `@Exclude` to the setters also, but the result is the same, the unwanted variables are stored to the document. I'll update the code in the question accordingly.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that some of the classes are stored to DB through GeoFirestore library, and some are stored by using regular Firestore. The issue here is the same in both cases.